# A word to explain thinking only in the short term

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I recently went through a phase where I was super interested in something and made a pretty big purchase for that hobby. A month later my interest completely died and the money was wasted. I'm looking for a word (or a few) to describe thinking only in the short term, not acknowledging that interests will change in the future.

I want to say, "that decision I made was so ____ I thought what I was interested in then then would be what I liked forever"

Comment: "near-sighted" or "miopic" might fit

Comment: Was thinking that it's something "impulsive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ideas:

> I bought the armadillo-grooming kit *on a whim.*  I have since lost interest and my armadillo ran away.

I didn't think much about the purchase.

---

> I am so *impulsive!* I bought my dandelion-bansai shears without really thinking about the time it would take to really master the art.

I often do things without *thinking them through.*

---

> Last month I made the *short-sighted* choice to buy a box full of snow.  It was good idea at the time, but summer is coming, and I have nowhere to keep it.

*Short-sighted* means that you think evaluate ideas in the short term (near future) without considering long-term ramifications.

Comment: Thanks, short sighted and impulsive are perfect words for what I am trying to describe.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Adam's great suggestions, if you want to emphasize the fact that you made the decision without thinking about it enough or more thoroughly, you could consider using the adjective "[hasty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hasty)" which means:

> Done with excessive speed or urgency; hurried: '*hasty decisions*'

Your example:

> The decision I made was so **hasty** (and not so well thought over). I
>   thought what I was interested in then would be what I'd like forever.